# How to loop this type of Json Data in Angular front end

Tags: json, angular

Please help me out to loop this below data in the 'Select dropdown' in Angular 10. I want to show all the States in India and its districts. I got this data from the net, but no idea to list them on the front end.

```
                {
                "AN": {
                    "name": "Andaman and Nicobar Island (UT)",
                    "capital": "Port Blair",
                    "districts": {
                        "1": "Nicobar",
                        "2": "North and Middle Andaman",
                        "3": "South Andaman"
                    }
                },
                "AP": {
                    "name": "Andhra Pradesh",
                    "capital": "Amaravati",
                    "districts": {
                        "1": "Anantapur",
                        "2": "Chittoor",
                        "3": "East Godavari",
                        "4": "Guntur",
                        "5": "Krishna",
                        "6": "Kurnool",
                        "7": "Prakasam",
                        "8": "Srikakulam",
                        "9": "Sri Potti Sriramulu Nellore",
                        "10": "Visakhapatnam",
                        "11": "Vizianagaram",
                        "12": "West Godavari",
                        "13": "YSR District, Kadapa (Cuddapah)"
                    }
                },}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Objects.keys:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
let states = Object.keys(this.data);
we will have list of states.
Each state is array 
state[0] code of state: AN
state[1] value of state: {name:...}
```

Here is the template:

```
<select formControlName="state" class="form-control">  
      <option disabled>Select State</option>  
      <option *ngFor="let state of states" value="state[0]">{{state[1].name}}</option>  
 </select>
```

...html of option equivalent to:

```
<option value="AN">Andaman and Nicobar Island (UT)</option>
```

You should modify the code according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions could be this.

```js
data = {
    "AN": {
        "name": "Andaman and Nicobar Island (UT)",
        "capital": "Port Blair",
        "districts": {
            "1": "Nicobar",
            "2": "North and Middle Andaman",
            "3": "South Andaman"
        }
    },
    "AP": {
        "name": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "capital": "Amaravati",
        "districts": {
            "1": "Anantapur",
            "2": "Chittoor",
            "3": "East Godavari",
            "4": "Guntur",
            "5": "Krishna",
            "6": "Kurnool",
            "7": "Prakasam",
            "8": "Srikakulam",
            "9": "Sri Potti Sriramulu Nellore",
            "10": "Visakhapatnam",
            "11": "Vizianagaram",
            "12": "West Godavari",
            "13": "YSR District, Kadapa (Cuddapah)"
        }
    },
};

constructor() {
  let array = Object.keys(this.data).map(key => this.data[key]);
  console.log(array);
}
```